# Asp.net MVC listening Channel in Socket.io server

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, socket.io

we have implemented a small Chat application wehre the usermanagement and all other Business Logic is done bis asp.net Mvc.

As signaling and Room Management wie use a socket io Server.

We have integrated a notification Channel from the mvc App to the Socket Server over JavaScript. Over this Channel wie get informations if some User join or left a room.
That is ok and works if somebody is logged in in the mvc App. But what Happens if nobody is logged is logged in and the Web App isnt called.

Here i miss all the notofications from the Socket because the is no listening Channel opened.

How can i handle the notification if nobody has startet the Web App. Is it possible to listen on a Channel on Server Side in a Web api? And how can i Open the listening channel all the Time in a Loop?

Do you Know a good Solution?

Thank you